# Show correct page name when linking in Skype, Facebook, etc

Tags: html, facebook, skype

I can't figure this one out,so I just made a small web page and when i link it in skype/facebook I don't get the name of the page in skype/facebook but instead I get.

"Open classfields installation", I assume this is from a previous "web platform" that I tested in the same domain.

How do I change that? My `<head>` looks like this

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My website title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
<link href="images/small_icon.png" rel="icon">
<meta name="description" content="My description">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/stylesheet.css">
```

Comment: [There's actually a neat little guide that shows how to control exactly what shows up](https://www.facebook.com/notes/hyperarts-web-design/set-up-your-website-to-control-images-text-in-facebook-status-update-links/10150320031290844/)

Comment: Try using [Facebook Lint](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint) for facebook to refresh the page cached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, be absolutely sure that you're sharing the right URL. I know it sounds dumb, but you should make sure that the page you expect is definitely there (and not being 302 redirected to, or in an iframe, or anything like that).

Once you've made sure of that, you can look at the page itself. From what you've written, it looks like you will probably need to add [OpenGraph meta tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects) to help sites see the page details clearly, for example:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Introducing our New Site"> 
<meta property="og:image" content="images/myimage.jpg"> 
<meta property="og:description" content="My amazing new site is amazing">
```

When that's done, you can ask Facebook to get the latest version (otherwise it will be a cached version) using their URL Linter:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

You can also debug your OpenGraph tags to ensure it's picking them up, too.

I don't believe there's a way to force Skype to get a new version of the URL, but the OpenGraph `meta` tags may help it see what you want it to see.

Comment: My page is not being redirected,i just checked to be sure.
It worked for facebook,everything seems fine,apart from a few errors ,but in general I get the name,image and description when i share it.

My in skype is stays the same ""Open classfields installation" without an image which is odd

Comment: Skype URL Preview is a new feature -- only two months old (http://blogs.skype.com/2015/12/03/skype-7-16-for-windows-app-making-it-easier-to-share-content/). It probably has a few kinks. It's possible the cached version is just on your computer -- can you try from a different machine?

Comment: turns out it was cached on my PC only,it works fine on other Devices

Answer (score 0):

try using below metadata

```
<meta property="og:title" content="title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="thumbnail_image" />
```